# How can I access dataloader variable from another method in another class?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pytorch

I do not have much experience with Python programming, especially with Tkinter per say. I have an issue in my application which requires me to bring another variable which has stored data in it to another Python module/file. I have two files which shows each unique tab in my Tkinter application. I want to use the `dataloader` variable from `get_data_transformed()` method to my other Python file for further use.

This line specifically has it initialized: `self.dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(self.dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=False)`

This is the code in one of my Python files, this is the code for one tab in my Tkinter application which is called dataset import tab:

```py
class DatasetImportWindow:
    """A class that creates a UI for loading and visualizing a model"""

    def __init__(self, master):
        """
        Initializes the ModelVisualization object.

        :param master: The parent widget.
        """

        self.master = master

        self.image_paths = []
        self.images = []

        self.heading_Label = tk.Label(
            master, text="Data Import Section", font=("Arial", 30)
        )
        self.heading_Label.pack(pady=20)

        self.data_Import_Button = tk.Button(
            master, text="Dataset Import", command=self.load_data, width=15, height=2
        )
        self.data_Import_Button.pack(anchor="center", pady=50)

        self.data_Transform_Button = tk.Button(
            master, text="Transform Data", command=self.get_data_transformed, width=15, height=2
        )
        self.data_Transform_Button.pack(anchor="center", pady=50)

        self.data_Imported_Label = tk.Label(
            master,
            text="",
            font=("Arial", 12),
        )
        self.data_Imported_Label.pack(pady=10)

        # self.visualize_model_button = ttk.Button(master, text="Visualize Model", command=self.visualize_model, state='disabled')
        # self.visualize_model_button.pack()

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width=700, height=500)
        self.canvas.pack()


    def get_data_transformed(self):
        """Returns the transformed dataset"""

        self.data_Transform_Button["state"] = "normal"
        
        self.dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root=self.get_directory(), transform=self.preprocess_mobilenetv3())

        self.dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(self.dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=False) # THIS LINE

        print("Dataset transformation complete. You can now move on to the next step.")

        return self.dataloader
```

The `dataloader` variable, I want to access in my other Python file which contains code for the other tab in the Tkinter application, I want to be able to use it in the `store_visualized_features()` method.

```py
from dataset_import_window import DatasetImportWindow


class FeatureExtractWindow:
    """A class that creates a UI for loading and visualizing a feature"""

    def __init__(self, master):
        """
        Initializes the FeatureVisualization object.

        :param master: The parent widget.
        """

        self.master = master

        self.feature_heading_Label = tk.Label(
            master, text="Feature Extraction Section", font=("Arial", 30)
        )
        self.feature_heading_Label.pack(pady=5)

        self.feature_choice_label = tk.Label(
            master,
            text="Please choose from the following models, through which the features will be extracted.",
            font=("Arial", 20),
        )
        self.feature_choice_label.pack(pady=20)

        self.load_mobilenet_model = tk.Button(
            master, text="MobileNet-V2", command=self.mobilenetv2_model
        )
        self.load_mobilenet_model.pack(pady=10)

        self.load_vgg_model = tk.Button(master, text="VGG-16", command=self.vgg16_model)
        self.load_vgg_model.pack(pady=10)

        # self.load_resnet_model = tk.Button(
        #     master, text="ResNet-50", command=self.resnet50_model
        # )
        # self.load_resnet_model.pack()

        self.load_inception_model = tk.Button(
            master, text="Inception-V3", command=self.inceptionv3_model
        )
        self.load_inception_model.pack(pady=10)

        self.note_label = tk.Label(
            master,
            text="Note: Only one model must be chosen.",
            font=("Arial", 15, "bold"),
        )
        self.note_label.pack(pady=20)

        self.model_Imported_Label = tk.Label(
            master,
            text="",
            font=("Arial", 12),
        )
        self.model_Imported_Label.pack(pady=10)

        # self.visualize_feature_button = tk.Button(
        #     master,
        #     text="Visualize Feature",
        #     command=self.visualize_feature,
        #     state="disabled",
        # )
        # self.visualize_feature_button.pack()

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width=100, height=100)
        self.canvas.pack()

    def store_visualized_features(self):
        """Stores the visualized features"""

        self.features = []
        self.labels = []

        for images, labels in self.dataloader: # THIS LINE
            with torch.no_grad():
                self.outputs = self.model(images)
                self.features.append(self.model(images))
                self.labels.append(labels)
```

I hope my question is clear. I am making an application with PyTorch in the backend and Tkinter as the frontend. Feel free to ask any further questions.

I have tried to bring in an instance of the class, `DatasetImportWindow` in the `__init__()` method for `FeatureExtractWindow` class but that just replaces all the content and I do not know how else to bring the variable in.

Comment: You need to use the existing instance of `DatasetImportWindow` to access `dataloader`.

Comment: @acw1668 I have tried that but it replaces the the content in the tab. 
```self.dataset_import_window = DatasetImportWindow(self.master)```. Should I put it outside the ```__init__()``` function?

Comment: I don't know your design, but I expect there is already an instance of `DatasetImportWindow` created.

Comment: @acw1668 Oh I do not have an existing instance already created as I have not brought over any other variables from  ```DatasetImportWindow```. Also, to get the specific variable from the method is what is confusing me the most.

Comment: That is why a [mre] is important to identify your problem.

Comment: Based on the posted code, I don't see that `self.dataloader` depends on other stuff in `DatasetImportWindow`.  So you may create just a function to return the `dataloader`.

Comment: @acw1668 from what I can see the `get_data_transformed` method does indeed return the `self.dataloader`. 
I think what @NevMthw was struggling with was how to pass it into the `FeatureExtractWindow` class. I posted an answer that could solve this hopefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `DatasetImportWindow` instance as an input to the `__init__` of `FeatureExtractWindow`

Example:

```
class DatasetImportWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dataloader = "Some Data"

    def get_data_transformed(self):
        self.dataloader = "Transformed Data"
        return self.dataloader

class FeatureExtractWindow:
    def __init__(self, data: DatasetImportWindow):
        self.inherited_data = data.dataloader

    def print_data(self):
        print(self.inherited_data)


data_1 = DatasetImportWindow()
data_1.get_data_transformed()

data_2 = FeatureExtractWindow(data_1)
data_2.print_data()
```

Output:

```
Transformed Data
```

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for the help. I just tried using your code but it seems that I am getting the error: ```AttributeError: 'DatasetImportWindow' object has no attribute 'dataloader'```. It comes for the ```self.inherited_data = data.dataloader``` line.

Comment: @NevMthw that's weird, the code is running perfectly on my PycharmCE:
[link]https://pasteboard.co/THM0wB3PCiuW.png
You're copying and pasting the code from my answer 'as is' or have you made any changes? are both classes in the same file?

Comment: @NevMthw if you mean that you tried changing your code based on my suggestions and get the error there could be a problem in the implementation in your main file where you create the instances. If this is the case please send me the code where you initialize the classes and pass one to another the same way I did here: 
`data_1 = DatasetImportWindow()
data_1.get_data_transformed()

data_2 = FeatureExtractWindow(data_1)
data_2.print_data()`

Comment: In my main.py file, I have initialized it as such which is here: https://pastebin.com/6w68AP3C

For the feature_extract_window.py file, this is the implementation: https://pastebin.com/LZ49CsT6

For the dataset_import_window.py file, there is no change. Also, yes both the classes are in separate files. Not in one Python file. Hope it is clear. Thanks.

I have commented the new lines added, accordingly.

Comment: @NevMthw I think it should be `self.inherited_data = data.get_data_transformed()` instead for your case.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. @acw1668 is right for the way that you wrote this.
Because the variable `self.data_loader` is not part of your __init__ method of the `DatasetImportWindow` class, until you don't call the `data.get_data_transformed()` method, the variable is not initialized. 
So you have 2 options:

Comment: a. go with the suggestion @acw1668 gave and use `self.inherited_data = data.get_data_transformed()` and that should work

b. add `self.data_loader = None` to your `DatasetImportWindow` class __init__. After you initialize it in main, call the `get_data_transformed()`. Only after that initialize an instance of `FeatureExtractWindow` and then the `self.data_loader` variable will already be initialized and have the value given by the `get_data_transformed()` method

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, @acw1668 and and Robert. Thanks to both of your suggestions, I was able to finally get it to work. I created a separate function which returns the ```data_loader``` variable and then initialize ```self.inherited_data = data.get_dataloader``` as an attribute instead of a method.

Comment: And lastly for the for loop, I put it as ```for images, labels in self.inherited_data()``` which seems to work and proceed through the loop. Maybe any of you could post an answer or revised answer which I can accept for future reference?